# how to write own shell that works with ssh

Tags: linux, bash, shell-script, shell

I tried several [tutorials](http://brennan.io/2015/01/16/write-a-shell-in-c/)
I modified usermod -s shell path_to_binary username

it does not work thru `winscp`, but works if use from Ubuntu terminal

I want to own shell, where I can control over commands and restrict users to some directories

Comment: Does your shell accept the `-c` flag?

Comment: I used this simple example, https://github.com/brenns10/lsh

Comment: So no?  I think that's your problem.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you are looking for a "[chroot jail for ssh](https://www.google.es/search?q=Chroot+Jail+for+SSH)", if the users require a terminal. Otherwise, if you just need they can access to their homes, configure `sshd` to `jail` `stfp` users in their homes:

add to `sshd_config`:

```
Match group myGroup  //Also can match users
    ChrootDirectory %h
    ForceCommand internal-sftp -u 0007
    AllowTcpForwarding no
    PermitTunnel no
    X11Forwarding no
```

Comment: no, I want to write my own shell like bash